# Delete last line from the file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I use `sed`  to quickly delete lines with specific position as

```
sed '1d'
sed '5d'
```

But, what if I want to delete the last line of the file and I don't know the count of lines (I know I can get that using `wc` and several other tricks).

Currently, using a workaround with `head` and `tail`combined with `wc` to do so. Any quick twists here?

Comment: @Nils I am on 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)'. Can you point for the options for `head` and `tail` you know of on different flavours?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

in sed `$` is the last line so to delete the last line:

```
sed '$d' <file>
```

Updated to include a way to delete multiple lines from the bottom of the file:

```
tac <file> | tail -n +3 | tac > <new_file>
```

- `tac` reads the file backwards (`cat` backwards)
- `tail -n +3` reads the input starting at the nth line
- `tac` reads the input and reverses the order back to the original

Comment: Use `sed -i '$d' <file>` to edit file in place.

Comment: somehow your answer didn't work without the top comment's suggestion i.e. without the `-i`. Why is it? i.e. `sed -i '$d' <file>` is needed for me.

Comment: Saved my LIFE! 

Answer (score 41):

$ for the last line:

```
sed '$d' file
```

Comment: Sadly though one has to use more complex techniques to delete, say, the last two lines.

Comment: What do you mean? `sed '$d' file; sed '$d' file`

Comment: @Rob: `sed '$d' file` doesn't actually modify the file; it just prints out the contents of the file, minus the last line. So `sed '$d' file; sed '$d' file` will print out the contents of the file *twice*, minus the last line each time. The delete-the-last-two-lines equivalent of `sed '$d' file` is `sed '$d' file | sed '$d'`.

Comment: That's what I had originally but changed it because I'm at work on a window box and couldn't check.

Comment: Yeah, that's inelegant but of course it works. I would do it in one pass with `sed -n '1{h;n;}; $q; x; p;'`. I was pouting that we can't just do `sed '$-1,$d'`.

Comment: `sed -i '$d' file` does the trick.

Comment: or `sed 'N;$!P;$!D;$d'`

Comment: somehow your answer didn't work without the top comment's suggestion i.e. without the `-i`. Why is it? i.e. `sed -i '$d' <file>` is needed for me.

Comment: sed -i ‘$d' <file> helped. "-i" will write automatcially. Thanks for the answer and comment.

Answer (score 16):

`cat file.txt | head -n -1 > new_file.txt`

Beware, it seems, depending on the last line of `file.txt` (if it ends with `EOF`, or `\n` and then `EOF`), the number of lines in `new_file.txt` may be the same (as `file.txt`) after this command (this happens when there is no `\n`) - in any case, the contents of the last line is deleted.

Also, note that you must use a second (intermediate) file. If you cat and redirect to the same file, you'll erase it.

Comment: Where this works, it could also be simply `head -n -1 file.txt > new_file.txt`. Note though that negative counts on `head -n` is only available for some implementations of `head`. For example, it doesn't work for FreeBSD's or for the BusyBox version of `head`.

Comment: @dubiousjim: Agreed, `head -n -1 file.txt > new_file.txt` is better. It works the same way with respect to my two comments (same number of lines, and, erase on same file). As for the negative argument, such differences occur from time to time between Unixes, and they are often frustrating because you expect it to be the same command entirely (and why wouldn't you - same name and purpose!) -- anyhow, good point. (I use Debian.)

Comment: head -n -1 doesn't seem to work in zsh. "head: illegal line count -- -1"

Comment: @JohnJiang It's not the shell that matters, it's the implementation of `head`. You are most likely not on a GNU system (possibly macOS?).

Answer (score 7):

`head --lines=-1`. I first stumbled across this possibility in the man-page for head on a SLES11SP2-system (coreutils-8.12-6.23.1)

`tail` and `head` are part of the `coreutils`-rpm (at least for rpm-based-systems).

According to the changelog of coreutils, this syntax is supported since coreutils-version 5.0.1

Bad news: According to the RH5-man-page this option is not described

Good news: It works with RH5 (so in your case: it works - at least with a current version of RH5).

`rpm -q coreutils` shows me (on CentOS 5.8):
coreutils-5.97-34.el5_8.1

I am not sure if RH5.5. already has the coreutils-version that supports it. But 5.5 has EoLed anyway.

Answer (score 7):

## Linux

#### $ is the last line, d for delete:

```
sed '$d' ~/path/to/your/file/name
```

## MacOS

#### Equivalent of the sed -i

```
sed -i '' -e '$ d' ~/path/to/your/file/name
```

Answer (score 3):

On Mac (BSD head/tail) you can use:

```
cat file.txt | tail -r | tail -n +2 | tail -r
```