# How do I delete the last n lines of an ascii file using shell commands?

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing

How do I delete the last `n` lines of an ascii file using shell commands?

Comment: @arved It's not a dublicate since this question is about the last **n** lines, not only the last line...

Comment: @chaos see this answer and replace 1 with n https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52818/11472

Comment: @arved Pedantically it's not a dublicate, but I see your point.

Comment: @Gilles has [an answer there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18815)

Answer (score 13):

With `head` (removes the last 2 lines):

```
head -n -2 file
```

With `sed`/`tac` (removes the last 2 lines):

```
tac file | sed "1,2d" | tac
```

`tac` reverses the file, `sed` deletes (`d`) the lines `1` to `2` (`2` can be any number).

Comment: Why is it when I try redirecting the output back into the file (OP asked to delete the lines of the file, after all), I just get a blanked file: `$ head -n -2 test-file > test-file`  When I pick another file name, the `head` output redirects as I would expect?  What's the best way to do the redirect into the same file?

Comment: @user1717828 The problem is that `bash` processes the redirections first, then executes the command. When `>file` is processed bash creates (if not existing) an empty file, else it is truncated. `head` then prints nothing because the file it reads is empty. You have to go via a temporary file. `head -n -2 file >tmp && mv tmp file`. BTW: all tools which allow "inplace editing" (like `sed -i`, `gawk -i inplace`, `perl -i`) do exactly the same.

Comment: `head -n -2` is great but is not supported by all versions of head, in particular the bsd version that ships with mac os :-(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the manpage for `head` - you can specify a number of lines, and it will give you that many lines out of a file.

```
head -10 filename
```

Gives first 10 lines of a file. If you don't know how long your file is, you can use `wc -l` to count the number of lines. And then use `head` to print the appropriate number.

Comment: question is about deleting n lines not outputing/print

Comment: `... | tee filename | sponge filename` can be valuable when you want to print it AND redirect it to a file.

Answer (score -2):

```
tac file| sed -i 'nd' | tac
```

`tac` reverses the file, `sed` deletes (d) the lines n numbers of lines

Comment: or `sed -i "\$-${n},\$d" file`